# error importing 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have the following line of code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
```

I get the following error:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' (/home/user-name/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/__init__.py)
```

I have this error BOTH on PythonAnywhere and on my local machine.
I am following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python)

I have read through [this post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/389) on github but to no avail.

What is missing? The objective i am trying to accomplish is to access a blob in a container when I have a URI and a shared key.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it on PythonAnywhere. What I did was:

`pip3.7 install azure-storage-blob --user` in the bash console and then

`python3.7 -c "from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 37):

Can you check `pip list` and make sure you have the latest version of azure-storage-blob i.e >= 12.0.0?

BlobServiceClient is introduced in 12.0.0.

If you have an older version, do
`pip install azure-storage-blob --upgrade`

Also, azure-storage-blob v 12.0.0 and above is moved to a different repository
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob

EDIT:
`azure-storage-blob` >= 12.0 is not compatible with the `azure-storage` meta package in case the issue persists after installing the latest major version of `azure-storage-blob`

Comment: I have azure storage version 12.5.0 but still getting cannot import baseblobservice module error.

Comment: @Ateeb BaseBlobService is deprecated from 12.0.0 - consider using BlobServiceClient

Comment: @rakshith92 I get the same problem as @Ateeb with `from azure.storage.blob import BlogServiceClient` and I have `azure-storage-blob` version `12.11.0` installed

Comment: Check `pip list` and see if you have `azure-storage` package installed. You will need to uninstall it

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I installed azure first and then I got this error. By doing the following steps, and it works fine now:

1. Uninstall azure-storage-blob using: pip uninstall azure-storage-blob.
2. Reinstall azure-storage-blob using: pip install azure-storage-blob.

Answer (score 2):

I also got stuck with this error especially when I was deploying Azure Web App(it worked fine at local pc).

I think first of all you should check your installed packages list again.

For my case, I had `azure-storage` and `azure-storage-blob` which was strange as I remember only installing `azure-storage-blob`. And I was getting exact same message as you.

like the answer from @Ivory, I also uninstalled both of them and tried installing all over again.

Then I got this error for `pip install azure-storage`,

```
Collecting azure-storage
  Using cached azure-storage-0.37.0.zip (4.3 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /tmp/8da918957b4378c/antenv/bin/python3.8 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-s_q2c_3c/azure-storage_855ccb98b522499ca9f42557f5036870/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-s_q2c_3c/azure-storage_855ccb98b522499ca9f42557f5036870/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-n2ov1yg9
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-s_q2c_3c/azure-storage_855ccb98b522499ca9f42557f5036870/
    Complete output (19 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-s_q2c_3c/azure-storage_855ccb98b522499ca9f42557f5036870/setup.py", line 55, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(message)
    RuntimeError:
    
    Starting with v0.37.0, the 'azure-storage' meta-package is deprecated and cannot be installed anymore.
    Please install the service specific packages prefixed by `azure` needed for your application.
    
    The complete list of available packages can be found at:
    https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/all
    
    Here's a non-exhaustive list of common packages:
    
    - [azure-storage-blob](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob) : Blob storage client
    - [azure-storage-file-share](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-share) : Storage file share client
    - [azure-storage-file-datalake](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake) : ADLS Gen2 client
    - [azure-storage-queue](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-queue): Queue storage client
```

You can see that there are error message telling that this `azure-storage` is deprecated.

So what you should do is(If you have both `azure-storage` and `azure-storage-blob` like I did):

1. `pip uninstall azure-storage`
2. `pip uninstall azure-storage-blob`
3. `pip install azure-storage-blob` again.
4. Try `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient` again, and it would work perfectly.

I hope this can help who stumbles upon this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the issue was either with the version of azure-storage-blob that I was using or the order in which I was installing the other azure libraries (common, core, etc). I uninstalled everything and just installed azure-storage-blob and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the previous solutions, but none worked for me.

I fixed it by changing the order in my `requirements.txt` file so that `azure-storage-blob` has priorty.

```
...
azure-storage-blob
azure-functions
...
```

Comment: Another thing I discovered: if you use an M1 Mac, you need to make sure you have [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/915#issuecomment-1717278022) working AND you create the `.venv` using the i386 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below line in the top into requirements.txt file works for me

azure-storage-blob