# how to read seismic data from blob storage in python (Without download)

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Trying to read data in a blob storage in python without downloading

**Code**

```
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

   STORAGEACCOUNTURL = ""
   STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = ""
   CONTAINERNAME = ""
   BLOBNAME = ""

   blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(
   account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

   blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(
    CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME, snapshot=None)
blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
   data = blob_data.readall()
   print(data)
```

**Error**

ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' (C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_*init*_.py)

Comment: Please state what you tried and the error you got in the question!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried in my environment that i can read the files in blob storage successfully.***

> ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' (C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob__init__.py)

The error occurs due to module in not installed properly kindly check the below commands

```
Pip3 uninstall azure-storage.blob
```

once uninstall again install the proper azure-storage module

```
 pip3 install azure-storage.blob
```

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

import os

STORAGEACCOUNTURL = "<Your storage account url>"

STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = "your storage account key"

CONTAINERNAME = "container name"

BLOBNAME = "pandas.json"

blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(

account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(

CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME)

blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()

data = blob_data.readall()

print(data)
```

***Portal:***

[image]

***Portal:***

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

#### Updated

When you have tried with lower version azure blob storage you will get an error below 12.0.0 will not below

- ***BlobServiceClient*** is introduced in 12.0.0.

When I tried with environment I got an same error:

[image]

I run the upgraded version of azure blob storage with commands:

```
pip install azure-storage-blob==12.13.1
```

Now when I run the code and got output successfully.

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkatesan, it's not worked. Still getting same error

Comment: Try this command pip install azure-storage-blob --upgrade

Comment: Getting same error ha?

Comment: Yes @Venkatesan

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768443/error-importing-blobserviceclient-from-azure-storage-blob) and also edited answer.

Comment: No its not work

Comment: Kindly help me what error are you getting now? have you tried all steps? kindly check the pip list whether the azure storage package are installed and it should be above 12.00 version

Comment: yes i tried all steps. but getting same error as mentioned before

Comment: sure Veknatesan

Comment: In discussion i have added screenshot regarding version kindly verify

Comment: @gomathi Check the updated answer

Comment: Sure @venkatesan will chk

Comment: @ venkatesan, still getting same error

Comment: Please what are the steps a have you done kindly ping in discussion chat? and error screenshot in your studio.

Comment: Hi @ Venkatesan, getting same error

Comment: not able to access discussion chat

Comment: Will you share once again

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/248257/room1?tab=general can you join here and post your error in screenshot

Comment: @ Venkatesam posted the error in chatroom

Comment: @gomathi Please check the chatroom

Comment: @ Venkatesan again getting error